# Pedagogical questions without reference to mathematics

Tags: discussion

If someone in the future will ask here a question about mathematics in general, one can tell him/her to look into math.SE.

As far as I know there is no general pedagogy/education SE. Of course, we have to close the question if it is completely unrelated to mathematics. What do we tell people asking such questions? Do we have to tell these people that such questions are not covered by any SE site? Or is there some site where we can sent them?

Comment: It is possible such a site will never get created. I think that we should allow all questions that directly aplly to math educators, even without mathematical content.

Comment: e.g. http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1032

Answer (score 6):

I think that questions about teaching that are applicable to mathematics are on topic here.  I do not think that we should care if they are also relevant to other subjects.  I might revise my opinion if we get flooded with such questions, but I do not think that that is likely.

Answer (score 4):

I will more or less try to echo what Neil said in this answer.

While we shouldn't evolve into a general pedagogy/education site, I think we should allow some general pedagogy/teaching questions. Even though teaching mathematics has its own specific challenges, I think that teachers across the board deal with many of the same issues. So we should allow any pedagogy question that has a relevance for math educators. That said, I don't think the OP can require that the answers be as general as possible. The answers on this site will come from teachers of mathematics and it should be expected that the answers will reflect this. There still needs to be a relevancy for math educators.

That some answers will find usefulness in other subjects isn't a crime.

Comment: I agree with your opinion and as long as people educationg mathematics get expertise from the questions here, we all have done a nice job. Maybe if we are flooded by questions in that kind, we have to talk again.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Math.SE (and even at CSc.SE), questions about "how do I teach ..." were allowed (if nothing else, because ME.SE didn't exist). I'd expect such questions will increasingly be (re)directed here in the future. Until there is a "general education" SE site, allow them here (with reservations). In the end, SE sites are created by common interest; if the interested parties aren't there, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: On Academia.SE university-level pedagogy is on-topic. Thus, if the only argument for you should be the lack of an alternative site, you might want to revise your opinion. (This does not mean you should, this is: for information only.)